# Makefile not exporting env var to submake unless defined in the same recipe

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnu-make, mingw-w64

Please see the below `Makefile`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash -euo pipefail

REPO_ROOT = $(shell pwd)
export VIRTUAL_ENV := ${REPO_ROOT}/venv
# bin = POSIX, Scripts = Windows
export PATH := ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${VIRTUAL_ENV}/Scripts:${PATH}

show-python:    ## Show path to python and version
    @echo -n "python location: "
    @python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable, end='')"
    @echo -n ", version: "
    @python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version())"

install: show-python
install:    ## Install all dev dependencies into a local virtual environment.
    export VIRTUAL_ENV="${VIRTUAL_ENV}"; \
    python -m pip install -r requirements-dev.txt --progress-bar off
```

The `install` recipe only works if I manually `export` the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` inside the recipe with `;` chaining it into the next command.  In other words, the first line of the `install` recipe is currently "doing something special" that I can't figure out.

What is going on here with this `export` being required twice?

Comment: There is no reason you should need to do this twice.  There must be something else going on here that is not in your question.  Please show the version of GNU make you're using, and enhance your recipes to show the value of `VIRTUAL_ENV` and `PATH`, by adding `echo $$VIRTUAL_ENV; echo $$PATH` (use the shell versions!).

Comment: @MadScientist thank you for your comment, it helped me move forward!  I posted an answer below, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am the OP).

**MINGW64: Didn't Work**

Per the comments, I updated the `Makefile` recipe:

```
install: show-python
install:    ## Install all dev dependencies into a local virtual environment.
    echo $$VIRTUAL_ENV; echo $$PATH; echo $$SHELL; echo $$BASH_VERSION
    python -m pip install -r requirements-dev.txt --progress-bar off \
        --extra-index-url $(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL)
```

It prints the below, where everything looks correct:

```bash
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV; echo $PATH; echo $SHELL; echo $BASH_VERSION
/c/path/to/repo/venv
/c/path/to/repo/venv/bin:/c/path/to/repo/venv/Scripts:/c/Users/user/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/user/bin:/c/Users/user/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/user/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Python38/Scripts:/c/Python38:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/cmd:/c/Users/user/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin:/c/Users/user/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims:/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
/usr/bin/bash.exe
5.1.16(1)-release
```

Note that I am using Git Bash from Git `2.38.1.windows.1` ([Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win)) with MINGW64 (installed via [`msys2-runtime 3.3.6-1`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/0b25881dffc7d1bd27d0138af8614b1dca969d6c/versions/package-versions-2.38.1-MinGit.txt#L48)).

**Cygwin: Works**

Next, I was like maybe it's a MINGW64 issue, so let me try [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html) (version `3.3.6-341.x86_64` which uses `bash` version `4.4.12(3)-release`).

Sure enough, it works out the box, no need for the pass-through `export VIRTUAL_ENV="${VIRTUAL_ENV}"; \`.

---

**Conclusions**

1. Use Cygwin instead of Git Bash
2. I opened an issue with MINGW64: https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/issues/16

Comment: I seem to have the same issue with makefile not passing environment down on windows, I am using bash on WSL.  I found a solution by instead using the 'env' command to launch sub-makes with modified environment. Ex: env VAR=1 $(MAKE) that would run the same makefile again with different environment. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The `export` of bash and the `export` of Make are not quite the same thing.

The former marks a bash variable to be passed to any child processes started later with `fork`. The latter marks a Make variable to be passed to any sub-Make launched later.

Your makefile does not use recursive make; that is, it does not launch any sub-Make. So your first `export` does nothing and can be removed.

Comment: Okay, I removed the `export` in front of `VIRTUAL_ENV` (line 4 in OP) on my machine's `Makefile`, and it didn't fix the issue.  I still need to have the pass-through `export VIRTUAL_ENV="${VIRTUAL_ENV}"; \ ` inside my `Makefile`'s `install` recipe.  Do you know how I can remove that part?

Comment: It is not true that `export` only marks variables to be exported to sub-makes.  `export` in a makefile marks a variable to be exported to ALL processes invoked by make, including normal recipes.

Comment: With `VIRTUAL_ENV := ${REPO_ROOT}/venv`, inside the recipe `echo $$VIRTUAL_ENV` prints an empty string.  With `export VIRTUAL_ENV := ${REPO_ROOT}/venv`, inside the recipe `echo $$VIRTUAL_ENV` prints the desired path.  So I confirmed the `export` needs to be there in with the `VIRTUAL_ENV` declaration